# Get iframe src param from inside the iframe itself if i dont have its id attribute but i have name attribute

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I get the iframe src param from inside the iframe itself if I don't have its id attribute but I have name attribute of it?

For example:

```
<iframe name="ambiguous" src="some src here"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get access like :

```
document.getElementsByName("ambiguus").item(0).getAttribute("src");
```

**Note :**

This solution works if the name is unique on your HTML page

---

*Reference*

- [getElementsByName MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Answer (score 0):

you can try frameElement.src on console if you're inside the iframe